# When opening a chrome browser, I am getting 'terms of services' window each time

Tags: google-chrome, watir-webdriver

I installed exe file(chromedriver_win_23.0.1240.0.zip ) from:http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the profile using [Alister Scott's example](http://watirwebdriver.com/chrome/)

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
profile['download.prompt_for_download'] = false
profile['download.default_directory'] = "/path/to/dir"
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :profile => profile
```